# How to send text within password element in https://e.mail.ru/login using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to make simple login script with selenium at `https://e.mail.ru/login`

I can fill email field by adding `?email=` after the link, so there is no problem, but driver can't find the password element, I tried the name, classname, xpath and css selector, and every time driver can't find the element. 
I've tried to use Selenium IDE addon in Firefox, used all the data which I could get from there with no luck.

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
(email, password, name, lname, id) = account.split(';')
driver.get('https://e.mail.ru/login?email=' + email)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='Password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in').click()
time.sleep(10)
print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to `switch_to_it()` and then locate the element inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://e.mail.ru/login?email=dark")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.ag-popup__frame__layout__iframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Password']"))).send_keys("Dark")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://e.mail.ru/login?email=dark")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='ag-popup__frame__layout__iframe']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Password']"))).send_keys("Dark")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: e_mail_ru]

Comment: @Dark Check out my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Yeah! It works, tyvm. Can you also help me with clicking the Sign in button? Nvm, figured it out!